# How to fix the Attribute error:'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape' in this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to make a recommendation system using the knn algorithm. I imported pandas(latest version 0.24) and created a sparse matrix. And now I am using reshape function but it is showing the error.

I am using Jupyter Notebook. And I have imported 3 CSV's.

```
books = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Shivam Upadhyay\\Desktop\\Project\\books\\BX-Books.csv', sep=';', error_bad_lines=False, encoding="latin-1")
books.columns = ['ISBN', 'bookTitle', 'bookAuthor', 'yearOfPublication', 'publisher', 'imageUrlS', 'imageUrlM', 'imageUrlL']
users = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Shivam Upadhyay\\Desktop\\Project\\books\\BX-Users.csv', sep=';', error_bad_lines=False, encoding="latin-1")
users.columns = ['userID', 'Location', 'Age']
ratings = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Shivam Upadhyay\\Desktop\\Project\\books\\BX-Book-Ratings.csv', sep=';', error_bad_lines=False, encoding="latin-1")
ratings.columns = ['userID', 'ISBN', 'bookRating']

query_index = np.random.choice(us_canada_user_rating_pivot.shape[0])
distances, indices = model_knn.kneighbors(us_canada_user_rating_pivot.iloc[query_index, :].reshape(1, -1), n_neighbors = 6)

for i in range(0, len(distances.flatten())):
    if i == 0:
        print('Recommendations for {0}:\n'.format(us_canada_user_rating_pivot.index[query_index]))
    else:
        print('{0}: {1}, with distance of {2}:'.format(i, us_canada_user_rating_pivot.index[indices.flatten()[i]], distances.flatten()[i]))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d2c9c594ec59> in <module>
      1 query_index = np.random.choice(us_canada_user_rating_pivot.shape[0])
----> 2 distances, indices = model_knn.kneighbors(us_canada_user_rating_pivot.iloc[query_index, :].reshape(1, -1), n_neighbors = 6)
      3 
      4 for i in range(0, len(distances.flatten())):
      5     if i == 0:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `pandas` documentation,

> Deprecated since version 0.19.0: Calling this method will raise an
>   error. Please call .values.reshape(...) instead.

See [pandas.Series.reshape](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.reshape.html#pandas-series-reshape) for more.